# ASP.NET Server control emitting server side tags

Tags: asp.net, render, custom-server-controls

I'm new to writing custom ASP.NET server controls, and I'm encountering the following issue:

I have a control that inherits from `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl`. I override the control's Render method, use the `HtmlTextWriter` to emit some custom HTML (basically a `TD` tag with some custom attributes), and then call the case class' Render method.

Using the control:

```
<dc:Header id="header1" runat="Server" DataColumn="MemberNumber" Width="30%">Member Number</dc:Header >
```

The problem is that when I view my rendered HTML, the server tag is emitted to the client as well (right after the `TD` tag):

```
<dc:Header id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_testData1_testData1_header1">Member Number</dc:Header>
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: This shouldn't happen - can you post your Render method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base render method emits the tagnames in `RenderBeginTag` and `RenderEndTag()`, just don't call it if you're doing your own rendering.  I also wouldn't inherit from `HtmlGenericControl` if you can help it, just inherit from `WebControl` or `Control` even if you need none of the `WebControl` attributes.

The normal `Render()` method does this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
   RenderBeginTag(writer);
   RenderContents(writer);
   RenderEndTag(writer);
}
```

As long as you call what you need, probably `RenderContents()` in your case, no need to call `base.Render(writer)`.

If you still want to override `HtmlGenericControl` be sure to set the [`TagName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.tagname(VS.80).aspx).